# Add attribute to input field when radio box is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, radio-button

I need to set an `onkeyup` attribute to an input box when a radio button is selected. 
So this is the input field I have:

```
<input type="text" name="searchval" value="<?php echo $search; ?>"  >
```

The radio buttons:

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="merchant" value="merchant"> Merchant<br>
<input type="radio" name="brand" value="brand"> Merchant<br>
</form>
```

So for example, when the "merchant" radio is selected, I want the input field to add `onkeyup="searchmerchant()"` to the input box so it should look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="searchval" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" onkeyup="searchmerchant()" >
```

How do I do this javascript?

---

EDIT: with code from Jayesh Chitroda's answer, I have created a fiddle:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qypLzc40/)

Comment: you can do that using `attr()`, `$('input[name="searchval"]').attr('onkeyup','searchmerchant()');`

Comment: the two radio buttons should add two different onkeyup attributes to the input box @dreamweiver

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Jquery:

```
 $('input[name="searchval"]').keyup(function(){
        console.log($('input[name=selection]:checked').val())
        var val = $('input[name=selection]:checked').val();
        if(val == 'merchant') { // check if selected radio is 'merchant' set onkeyup attribute
            $(this).attr("onkeyup","searchmerchant()")
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr("onkeyup"); // Remove if not merchant selected
        }
  });
```

Html:

Assign same name to both radio button and update values of radio button.

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="selection" value="merchant"> Merchant<br>
  <input type="radio" name="selection" value="brand"> Brand<br>
</form>
```

Comment: ` $(this).attr("onkeyup","searchmerchant()")` here can I use the id of the input box instead of "this"?

Comment: yes you can set id of input, but for that you need to add id attribute in input tag first

Comment: yes I added the id="s" and $('#s').attr but not working

Comment: onkeyup attribute is being added on keyup...if merchange is checked..can you tell whats not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112339/discussion-between-yohan-blake-and-jayesh-chitroda).